# How to determine Flutter ImagePicker() window size and position?

Tags: flutter-image-picker

When `ImagePicker()` opens gallery in my app, the window appears at the bottom of the screen covering my advertisement banner. Is it possible to open it at the top of the screen or determine its maximum size? Also padding of `imagepicker` gallery window would be useful.

I don't have an idea to solve it.